# React can't download pdf file on the server

Tags: html, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import Navigation from "../components/Nagivation";

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <div className="home">
            <Navigation/>
            <div className="homeContent">
                <div className="content">
                    <div className="pdf">
                        <a href="./media/AA.pdf" target="_blank">CV Download</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

The file is into `app/public/media/AA.pdf`

locally it works very fine, `App.pdf` is open. But on the AWS server, it doesn't. It opens [www.aaaa.com/media/AA.pdf](http://www.aaaa.com/media/AA.pdf) but error the page doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added `download` attribute
`<a href="./media/AA.pdf" download="CV.pdf">CV Download</a>`